# Why is the recurrence $f_n=\frac{5f_{n-1} + 1}{25 f_{n-2}}$ cyclic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

Given:

$f_1 = a$

$f_2 = b$

and

$f_n =  \dfrac{5f_{n-1} + 1}{25 \cdot f_{n-2}}$

You can just start doing the algebra to show

$f_3 = \dfrac{5b + 1}{25a}$

$f_4 = \dfrac{5a + 5b + 1}{125ab}$

$f_5 = \dfrac{5a + 1}{25b}$

$f_6 = a$

$f_7 = b$ .....

But why is this happening i.e. what in the definition of the recurrence makes this cyclic and determines the cycle length?

Comment: You can show that any rational function (that is, something of the form $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$) will do this.

Comment: @Prasiortle What are the arguments to your rational function? $f_n$ is dependent on two previous values, not just one, and if you mean for $x$ to be e.g. the ratio $\frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}}$ then I'm pretty sure that's not correct...

Comment: It works even if you replace $5$ with $c$ and $25$ with $c^2$.

Comment: This is a slight variation on the Lyness 5-cycle: $x_n = (x_{n-1}+1)/x_{n-2}.$

Comment: Cool - do you happen to have a good reference point for that?